# How to use webshim with assetic in a Symfony2 project?

Tags: javascript, symfony, assets

I would like to use [Webshim](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/) in a Symfony2 project.

So far, the webshim library is in mybundle/Resources/public/components/webshim...
The webshim library has a polyfiller.js that loads specified scripts from the ./shims directory. This is also clearly explained from the [webshim docs:](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/#Requirejs-setup)

> The code inside of the polyfiller.js automatically detects the path to the script it is run from and assumes, that the shims folder is in the same directory. This means, you have to make sure, that either the shims folder is placed parallel to the code of the polyfiller.js or to configure the path using the basePath option.

I'm using other libraries and they all end in the /web/js or /web/css directories as they should do. They are combined and have names like "6464de0.js" and are perfectly accessible.

But, webshim tries to load scripts from the shims folder. This makes sense when you look at the docs.

This is an example of 404's in the console:

```
GET http://domain.dev/app_dev.php/js/shims/combos/1.js 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I make the webshim library work with assetic?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and here is what I did:

Put the 'shims' folder in the public folder of your desired bundle (eg. AcmeBundle/Resources/public/js/shims) then when you do assets:install using the console command it will be installed in the Symfony/web directory.

Then set the webshim option so that it points to that path:

```
webshim.setOptions('basePath', '/bundles/acme/js/shims/');
```